# Will cockroach poison traps harm geckos?

Tags: pest-control

I live in a Hong Kong village house and here it's common to have Chinese geckos living in the house. They've been pretty unobtrusive so far and they do eat mosquitoes so I definitely wouldn't want to harm them.

Recently we've spotted cockroaches on a few occasions and were considering getting some poison traps like [the ones linked here](https://www.ztore.com/en/product/roach-baits-1006418?gclid=Cj0KCQiAmsrxBRDaARIsANyiD1oPP80P4lcYBMzghDp05rYQSOLXV1kTv66RerL93lSA3L1sm3I-gdcaAm6xEALw_wcB). Does anyone know if we're likely to poison the geckos as well if we install those? I guess the bait is unlikely to be directly attractive to geckos but will the poison spread through the food chain?

Comment: What do geckos eat? My only contact with the species is auto insurance.

Comment: Love that . don’t they eat mealworms? Or was that chameleons? + for the funny. I guess it could get in the food chain but I would expect larger animals to be affected like birds that eat bugs.

Comment: They eat pretty much all insects, including cockroaches. I guess if small birds aren't affected, neither would be geckos.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about animal tolerance of poisons.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That one eats American consumers bank accounts. ( i have fed that little green bas!*rd for years )

Comment: use boric acid instead, it works very well against roaches. While i don't see info specific to geckos, borax is a common ingredient in food and medicine, and harmless to mammals, very much unlike indoxacarb.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in Japan in the 1970's we were told that the geckos will eat the roaches. Fewer geckos means more roaches. I would assume any dead roaches would contain the poison. Any geckos eating roaches that had consumed the poison would be contaminated.